# Creating Node table is not working in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2107 version. When I try to create a NODE table to get familiarized with Graph tables. I am using the below syntax to create the table and I am getting an error like "Incorrect syntax near AS." Can anyone please write what the issue is?

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
  EmpID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  FirstName NVARCHAR(50)
) AS NODE;
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near AS.

I am also posting what I am getting for `SELECT @@VERSION`

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0  (Build 16299: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: You should check the compatible level.

Comment: I am not sure what the compatible level is but when I run this statement "SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases;" I am getting the compatibility_Level as 140. Please let me know if this is ok, if not how to change?

Comment: What SSMS you are using ?

Comment: 2017 Developer edition              Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 16299: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: But this is working for my co-worker who has the same version. Not sure what would be the problem.

Comment: . . . . As far as i know this would required `SSMS` SQL Server 17.1 (or higher). So, you can download from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017 if you don't have a one this.